# AWVERIFY not propergating

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service

Yesterday at about 3pm, I setup awverify records for two website I want to transfer from one Azure account to another. By the end of the day Azure still wasn't allowing me to add my domains, so I took a gamble and re-pointed the domain and www sub-domain to the new IP. This morning of course my sites were down and Azure still won't accept my domains. I've had to point the domain and www sub-domain back to the old IP.

Obviously I'm expecting the response that the awverify CNAME hasn't propagated, but my DNS, and others I checked online, changed within an hour. Why would Azure take 18 hours and counting?

I'm quite sure I've set it up correctly...
[image: Azure error requesting AWVERIFY CNAME]

[image: DNS lookup for AWVERIFY showing the correct CNAME]

[image: DNS control panel]

Comment: David, how did you configure `wired-digital.co.uk` domain name in your DNS?

Comment: Hi Tom. I added another image to show the additional CNAME record I added the top two records point to the old server still

Comment: I can access `wireddigital.azurewebsites.net` as well as `www.wired-digital.co.uk` (including `wired-digital.co.uk`) and I am getting the same page on any of those URLs. Is your problem resolved now?

Comment: No. Those URLs point to the old server. I would like to change the server that they point to without any down time on the website. It must be possible to setup the new server with those domains and then change the DNS afterwards.

Comment: Sorry but I misunderstood your question. If you are planning to switch your application quite often, I would also suggest reading a bit more about [Traffic Manager Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh744833.aspx) - that may help you in the future. But it's a very interesting question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, though I can't find this documented elsewhere. The cause of the issue is that I was migrating from one Azure account to another. It seems that Azure will not allow two website (even in different accounts) to use the same host names.

Once I deleted the host names from the old account, I was able to add them to the new account.

I can see why this would be the case, but it should be documented somewhere as I can't be the first person to run in to this.